# How can I selectively return full XML properties in one method and partial in another using the same C# class?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a problem with serialization c# in .net

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Is possible to control by code without adding more bool fields IdSpecified, NameSpecified and on?

I cant use any third party library, and cant use attributes [XmlIgnore], the main idea is use same class but for one method i want to return xml full properties and another method return some properties.

Any ideas or suggestions for solve this?

I solved this problem with adding specified properties for each one... but im not satisfied with this solution...

[XmlIgnore] just ignored my property in both cases.

Maybe a custom attribute? Im open for any suggestions or ideas..

Comment: Maybe create a "lightweight" class with the partial properties and then a full class that extends the lightweight class? Then you can choose which class you return in your method.

Comment: Suggest you try `ShouldSerialize` - I've only used this with Json, not XML, but this suggests it would do the trick: https://blog.jsinh.in/shouldserialize-conditional-xml-serialization-using-csharp/

Comment: both solutions ive already thought, however my class is too big and is like: inherited from another class...

im trying to avoid to create more classes, and make something generic like making a generic with PropetyInfo..

the best solution ive found is using third party library where we can create temporary fields when we read all fields from the class that was easy to create specifiedfields and serialize, then disregard all temporary fields.. but unfortunnaly i cannot use this in my project..